# Использование OpenCV в Java

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, opencv

Туплю над простым программным кодом. Пишу на Java в NetBeans с использованием OpenCV.
Вот код

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java249");
CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_fullbody.xml");
VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);
if(!cap.isOpened())
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cam can not found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

Mat frame = new Mat();
cap.retrieve(frame);
Highgui.imwrite("cek.jpg", frame);
cap.release();
Mat resim = Highgui.imread("cek.jpg");
MatOfRect rect = new MatOfRect();
cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(resim, rect);
Scalar renk = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);
for(Rect dik : rect.toArray()){
    Core.rectangle(resim, new Point(dik.x, dik.y), new Point(dik.x+ dik.width, dik.y+dik.height), renk);
}
System.out.println(rect.height());
Highgui.imwrite("dene.jpg", resim);
}
```

Вот вроде всё верно. а на деле выделения человека в рамку не происходит.

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться со статьёй [Как создать краткий, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

у detectMultiscale есть чуть побольше параметров, чем джва указанных вами. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801015/recommended-values-for-opencv-detectmultiscale-parameters

Как минимум, нужно явно указать minSize и maxSize